# Content Length and Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to upload an XML file using Invoke-WebRequest (Invoke-RestMethod isn't recommended for that?) but when trying to set the content-length in the header, I get the error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.
```

Do I need to create a request stream? I've checked https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d18f4ae9-4a5d-495f-aa2d-fbda3d616967/invokewebrequest-you-must-write-contentlength-bytes-to-the-request-stream-before-calling but that doesn't seem to answer that.

```
$requestHeaders = @{
    "content-length" = 2182
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml"
    "Authorization"  = "Bearer " + $response.access_token
}

$body = @"
    $xml
"@

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri "{uri}" -Headers $requestHeaders -Body $Body
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"content-length" = 2182`, without the quotes around the number?

Comment: Good catch! Changed it but still get the same error :( Updated in the code.

Comment: `Content-Length` needs the number of bytes I believe, so perhaps your value of 2182 does not match the **byte** length of `$xml`?  Try `"Content-Length" = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetByteCount($xml)` or `"Content-Length" = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetByteCount($xml)`

Comment: Nice! I tried this and it actually did get me closer to figuring out the issue - turned out to be setting Transfer-Encoding = chunked. Will post an answer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out @Theo's comment, I put in Transfer-Encoding into the header and it looks like it worked! Full fixed code:

```
$requestHeaders = @{
#content-length not needed?
"Transfer-Encoding" = "chunked"
"Content-Type" = "application/xml"
"Authorization"  = "Bearer " + $response.access_token
}

try {

   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "{uri}" -Headers $requestHeaders -Body $xml

} catch {

    # write exception message

    $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
    $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
    $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
    $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
    Write-Host $responseBody

}
```

Comment: This did not work for  me.  I get Invoke-RestMethod : The 'Transfer-Encoding' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. in powershell 3.0.